# How to add custom order state to shopware 6

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

For shopware 6 i want to add some custom order statusses to the core.

With the DAL i managed to add these on activating my plugin, but now the are not selectable in the administration. So i cannot change my order to this new custom state.

Anybody who can help me make this status selectable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you look at the [state machine ERD](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/core/erd/shopware-core-system-statemachine) you see a quite complex setup regarding states. There is a table called state_machine_transition which might be missing some entries in your case:

[image: state machine ERD]

In the [docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/core/checkout-process/order) it is an overview of the state machine of the devlivery state, what I assume is your new state in. In the state machine graph you can see all available states and all transition steps that are available to change from on state to the other.

[image: delivery state machine]

I assume you are missing such a transition step. As soon as you add a transition step the administration should allow you to step to it. Make sure to integrate your new state so it can be changed from and to it back and forth in any case. This prevents a user to be locked in a deadend.

Comment: Hi Joshua Behrens, Thanks for the detailed explanation. In the end i was missing the transition steps indeed, by adding these into the database as well during the install life-cycle event of the plugin  everything is working perfect now

Answer (score -1):

You can change the state using method [transition of class StateMachineRegistry](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/System/StateMachine/StateMachineRegistry.php#L156)

Here is the right way to add a custom state to order, order transaction, shipping -

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/order/using-the-state-machine